# TPL Dataflow with Rx: Observer misses messages

Tags: c#, system.reactive, tpl-dataflow

In the sample coding below, the source and IObservable and also part of a pipeline. The sink at the end of the pipeline gets all the messages. But the observer gets only the first and last messages.

```
    public class Test
{
    public static async Task Run()
    {
        var source = new BroadcastBlock<int>(x => x);
        var transform = new TransformBlock<int, int>(x => x * 2);
        var sink = new ActionBlock<int>(x => Console.WriteLine($"from ActionBlock: {x}"));

        source.LinkTo(transform);
        transform.LinkTo(sink);

        var observable = source.AsObservable();

        IDisposable subscription = observable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"from observer: {x}"));

        await source.SendAsync(1);
        await source.SendAsync(2);
        await source.SendAsync(3);
        await source.SendAsync(4);
        await source.SendAsync(5);
        await source.SendAsync(6);

        subscription.Dispose();
    }
}
```

```
from observer: 1
from ActionBlock: 2
from ActionBlock: 4
from ActionBlock: 6
from ActionBlock: 8
from ActionBlock: 10
from ActionBlock: 12
from observer: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

From a [relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70481) regarding similar problems with the `WriteOnceBlock<T>`:

> at present WriteOnceBlock composability with AsObservable isn't perfect.

([Stephen Toub commented on Jun 30, 2022](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70481#issuecomment-1170538096))

If I a was you I wouldn't mess with TPL Dataflow and Rx interop. It seems that these two technologies have not been rigorously tested together, and there are bugs lurking in there. Bugs that currently no one cares about, because no one actually uses these two technologies together to do anything serious.

Comment: Thanks Theodor,  I think I see the point. In the situation above do you think it has to do with the activation and completion of the block that is an IObservable? After all, it seems it only emit the first and last message.

Comment: I am trying to understand how two pipelines communicate with each other, especially when the messages exchanged at a difference pace from those received through the pipeline.

Comment: @DavidY I have no idea what's happening under the hood. The TPL Dataflow [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow) is too complicated for me to understand by just reading it.